# Y axis from one column x from different column into different subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hi I have a dataframe liek this:

```
data1 = {"x": [10,20,30,40,50], 
         "y": [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05],
         "z": [0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15],
         "q": [0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25],}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['x','y','z','q'])
```

And I want to create a plot of x against y, against z, and against q as subplots on a plot.

I have done this, but they are on the same plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df1['y'], df1['x'])
plt.plot(df1['z'], df1['x'])
plt.plot(df1['q'], df1['x'])
```

Additonally is there a way I can add a label for eahc line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add legend to each line, you could assgin each line with a label, then call `plt.legend()` to draw the legend.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = {"x": [10,20,30,40,50], 
         "y": [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05],
         "z": [0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15],
         "q": [0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25],}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['x','y','z','q'])

plt.plot(df1['y'], df1['x'], label='y')
plt.plot(df1['z'], df1['x'], label='z')
plt.plot(df1['q'], df1['x'], label='q')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

To plot them on different subplots, you could create mxn subplots by defining the `nrows` and `ncols` parameters in `plt.subplots()`. Then plot data on each axes object.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = {"x": [10,20,30,40,50], 
         "y": [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05],
         "z": [0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15],
         "q": [0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25],}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['x','y','z','q'])

figure, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 4))

axs[0].plot(df1['y'], df1['x'], label='y')
axs[1].plot(df1['z'], df1['x'], label='z')
axs[2].plot(df1['q'], df1['x'], label='q')

axs[0].set_title('x against y')
axs[1].set_title('x against z')
axs[2].set_title('x against q')

plt.show()
```

[image]